# Deployment partially failing after updating to Google Cloud Endpoints 2.0

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, migration, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I recently updated my Google AppEngine project to use Cloud Endpoints 2.0.
After the migration I tried to deploy my code using appcfg. The deployment is stuck at some point and it keep on retrying.
When I check the log, it seems the tool is accessing /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs, which is giving 404.
Is it a bug in my side or with the tool? Because the migration document says to replace the /_ah/spi with /_ah/api.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try deploying to a new App Engine version?

Comment: I am using the new app engine version (1.9.54)

Comment: I tried redeploying but still not working. I updated the version to 1.9.59